# My C program won't converted int to char into mqtt broker message by execvp

Tags: c, char, int

Somehow my conversion from int to char is not accepted by execvp. It won't write any text in my bash. But if i state -> Data = "134"; it works. Seems like the conversion is an issue and that the function acknowledge this.

How do I solve the issue? in the end I want to send my digital values where str is.

```
int set1 = 134;
int set2 = 2;
int set3 = 3;

char *Data;
Data = (char) set1;

char *str[80];
strcpy(str, "some,");
strcat(str, "text,");
strcat(str, Data);

char *name[] = {
    "mosquitto_pub",
    "-d",
    "-t",
    "SomeName",
    "-m",
    str,
    NULL
};
execvp(name[0], name);
```

Comment: What is the return value of `execvp`? Does your `errno` change?

Comment: Don't use casts.

Comment: `man sprintf` is your friend

Comment: @KerrekSB Why? is there a particular reason? http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson11.html

Comment: @Dai I don't know. How can I check it? I start this function as a child because rest of my program have to continue. If I just made the function inside my main program, that execution ends the process it's called from.

Comment: @hardillb You solved it for me. Big thanks!

Comment: Why the negatives? To little information regarding my issue? hardillb solved my problem.

Comment: @Christian: Because casts generally lead you down the wrong path. As you can see :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Haha... word. But it would be interesting to understand why forced cast conversion wasn't accepted and sprintf function was.

Comment: @Christian: Because the cast converts the value of the int to pointer value, which is essentially meaningless. It does not magically perform string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int set1 = 134;
int set2 = 2;
int set3 = 3;

char con[80];
char *Data;
sprintf(con, "%d", set1); /*Thanks to hardillb*/
Data = con;    

char *str[80];
strcpy(str, "some,");
strcat(str, "text,");
strcat(str, Data);

char *name[] = {
    "mosquitto_pub",
    "-d",
    "-t",
    "SomeName",
    "-m",
    str,
    NULL
};
execvp(name[0], name);
```